# dependency check failure on oracle linux

Tags: linux, dependencies, packet, installation

i am new on linux. i am using oracle linux... el5. i am trying to install oracle 11g. 
i have to install some packets for pre-installation task. ex: compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3 
i downloaded the rpm file and tried to install but i got a dependency check failure. 
i have a later version of glibc as it can be seen below. what should i do? sould i install ALL the dependencies even if i had a later version?

```
[root@localhost ferhat]# rpm -iv compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64.rpm
warning: compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID e8562897
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64
        libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64
        libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64
        libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3)(64bit) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64
        libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61.x86_64
[root@localhost ferhat]# 
[root@localhost ferhat]# 
[root@localhost ferhat]# rpm -q glibc
glibc-2.5-49
[root@localhost ferhat]# rpm -q gcc
gcc-4.1.2-48.el5
```

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Use your package manager instead of pure RPM for installing. What is it in your distribution, yum?